# iPhone home screen not showing after erasing network and content settings

Tags: iphone

I have erased my network and content setting from iPhone 5s. Now my home screen does not show anything. I want my home screen icons and apps back. How can I do that, or how can I reinstall them? I want this screen, kindly help me out.

[image: Example of iPhone home screen]

Comment: Are you just left with the default iPhone apps? Messages, Calendar, Photos, etc?

Comment: i have nothing on my home screen.i-e No Messages, No  Calendar, No  Photos etc

Comment: Did you apply a jailbreak on your iPhone?

Comment: No jailbreak @patrix

Answer (score 1):

If you have not powered off the phone recently, try that. A reboot often works wonders. Also what happens if you swipe right to left, do you get other apps? Are there 2 or more dots centered just above the dock? What I am getting at is it may be that you just have a blank home screen and all your apps have somehow moved to other screens. Swiping might reveal them and allow you to move them back.

Wiping just the network setting should affect nothing else. I've done it many times and never an app out of place.

Hopefully you have backed up your phone recently, you may have to restore from backup.

Comment: No three dots just normal screen without any icons.

Comment: If you have a backup I would erase the phone from Settings (as below) and restore it from the backup you made after getting the phone and setting it up... You DID back up the phone? ;-)

Comment: Actually it's new mobile,i just check the functionality of erase content,it ruin me,no i didn't backup,because i have no data at all.

Comment: I got this page back,after signing in from my icloud ID,i want to jail break my iphone 5s,(Ios 7.1.1),is it safe or not?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, powering the phone off and turning it back on is one option.

Another option is to reset it which involves pressing and holding both the power button (top right) and the home button (bottom front center).

The reset process should not affect user data, but should reset some settings that may cause the screen to display correctly.

There is also a software reset (inside iOS 7) through General -> Reset -> Reset Home Screen Layout. I have not personally tried this but it may correct your situation.

The Reset page also includes reset options that erase all data and settings. You may want to try one of those.

Have you backed up your phone to your computer lately?

If none of these options work, and the phone is new, I suggest taking it back to the store where you made the purchase.

HTH.

Comment: ,i already apply these instructions,but all is in vain.Don't know what happened,it is brand new mobile,i am really worried about my new set..

Comment: @MuhammadAli, I edited my answer with some other suggestions.

Comment: thanks for your co-operation,but the dilemma is that i am now in Pakistan and i purchased mobile from USA.None of the mention above reasons work.:(